# Python Pandas DataFrame fillna() cannot work correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame `df` which has 300000 rows and 75 columns. One of Columns of this dataframe has 165 NaN.
I want to use the `fillna()` to fill up the null value, but it seems that Nothing really happens. The 165 NaN values are still there.
What my code is as follows:

```
df=df.fillna({'Col':df['Col'].mean()})
```

I don't know why it didn't work. Is it because of the large amount of NaN values?

Comment: Are you trying to `fillna()` on a particular column with the mean of that column?

Comment: If so, use; `df['Col'] = df['Col'].fillna(df['Col'].mean())`...

Comment: Can you make an [example DataFrame that exemplifies the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/2087463)?

Comment: Check the column name for whitespaces etc. It looks correct.